# Incompatible type 'double'

Tags: objective-c

I'm assigning a CGFloat animatedDistance and I'm getting this error.

Here I'm assigning value to animatedDistance

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 140;
```

heightFraction is CGFloat as well.

```
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
   animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
else
{
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
```

What type should be animatedDistace? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`floor` returns a `double`. On some platforms, `CGFloat` is a `float`. `animatedDistance` should be typed as a `double` (you can cast it to a `CGFloat` if needed).

Comment: You can implicitly cast between `double` and `float`. You might get a warning, depending on how paranoiac you've set the compiler to be, but it's not a hard error unless you've asked for it to be so.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get a vector... `CGpoint vector = ccpSub(cgpoint 1, cgpoint 2);`
And if you want double/float values then do this:

CGpoint.location

for whatever you are trying to find the coordinates of, then assign a float to `CGPoint.location.y` and another float to `CGPoint.location.x`

You need cocos2d for this by the way. I think.

Comment: `CGPoint` doesn't have a `location` member; it *is* a location. And how does `ccpSub`, which subtracts one point from another, help the questioner multiply one distance by a fraction?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you declared `animatedDistance` as holding some kind of pointer, such as `NSNumber *`, or a structure, such as `CGSize`. Either way, you can't assign a `CGFloat` there.

If `animatedDistance` holds an NSNumber object, create one around the value. Back when you asked this question, the way to do this was `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:floor(…)]`. Now, you can just use `@(floor(…))`.

If `animatedDistance` holds a `CGSize` or other structure, you're going to have to decide for yourself how to meaningfully convert from the single number you have to the kind of structure you want.